# Facebook FQL API returning empty array

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-insights

I have made sure that the user has 'read_insights' permission. I also have 'manage_pages' permission. I receive no errors which is kind of annoying as it woud help.

All I ever get is an empty array. The Graph API works just fine, returning correct data every time.

FQL does not work, and I have never got Insights from it yet. Either they have a bug or I'm doing something wrong.

I have this code to get some Insights:

```
$('.page-entry>a').live('click', function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
            FB.api(
                {
                    access_token: accessToken,
                    method: 'fql.query',
                    query: 'SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id = ' + id + ' AND metric="page_impressions" AND end_time=end_time_date("2012-06-01T07:00:00+0000") AND period=period("month")'
                },
                function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            );
        })
```

The user is logged in, and I can see all of their pages/apps fine. I have the id's and even access_tokens for each page. I tried that for FQL, it didn't work.

Any help appreciated.